# the number of running mappers in a hadoop job

Tags: hadoop-streaming

Using `streaming`, I set the number of `map` to `200`, like this:

`-D mapred.map.tasks=200 -D mapred.job.map.capacity=200`

But later I found that the number of **running mappers** is just **9**, with *500+ mapper tasks pending.* This looks pretty weird to me, cuz I think there should `200` running, right? WHY just 9 running?

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers is actually controlled by the Inputformat you use.

Inputfiles are split according to the format and each split makes a map.

Some more information can be found [on the Apache Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces)

Comment: Well, when I submitted the job, there are 500+ mapper tasks in total, which I think should invoke 500+ mappers, right? But why the number of running mappers just 9?

Comment: Does your system actually support 500 running mappers? It is controlled by the number of map slots per node